# Windows driver certificates

Tags: windows, certificate, driver, code-signing

I'm trying to add a signature to my usb driver for windows 8 64 bit. 
Is it possible to use any SSL-certificate for signature or should I use some special certificate for drivers?
Does anybody have experience with GoDaddy Standard SSL for multiple domains (I've heard this certificate allows to add digital signature for driver)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, certificates are not "SSL certificates".  They are X.509 certificates.

In your case you need a code-signing certificate. But not each code signing certificate will work. Only those from Verisign and GlobalSign CAs will. [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/code-signing/) seems to be cheaper.

Also check http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/install/drvsign/crosscert.mspx for cross-signing certificate (you'll need to add one to your signature).

Comment: Thanks. I've found a code-signing certificate from [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/code-signing-certificate.aspx "GoDaddy"). Is this the right one?

Comment: @D051P0 No, as I mentioned, it won't work for drivers. You MUST use globalsign- or verisign- issued one. The reason is simple - there are no cross-signing certificates available for certificates by other CAs.